# How do you set the Scheduled Tasks "Run only if logged in" option from the command line?

Tags: windows-xp, command-line, google-chrome, sp3, scheduled-tasks

I want to create some tasks with the "Run only if logged in" option set, but using a batch file, as you can in the user interface version of the schtasks.exe tool.

I'm doing this so I don't have to specify a password, either in the batch file, or when the batch file is run... I would use /ru System but I can't because the tool I'm automating (SyncToy 2.1) won't run with that account because I am hitting a network drive...

Also, I noticed that Google Chrome sets up some tasks with this option set during installation, so I'm thinking there must be a way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're brave, you could modify the .job file directly, it's a single byte that you change from 0x00 to 0x20 by the looks of things, you'll find the file in %windir%\tasks

Comment: then I'll start using the /IT switch as answered by CGA when I move to Windows 7...

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb736357%28VS.85%29.aspx) is a link to the available switches for schtasks.exe. I think you're looking for th /IT switch.

Comment: /IT switch would be ideal but unfortunately it's not available in Windows XP SP3